# Chinese remainder theorem

Tags: algorithm-design

1. Z/11Z[X] is the finite field
2. P(2) = 4
3. P(3) = 3
4. P(5) = 7

How can I solve my congruence system with polynoms?

I made my system of congruence like that :

- X = 2 [4]
- X = 3 [3]
- X = 5 [7]

And it gives me 54 = 10 [11]
So, X is 10 [11]

But i still don't know how to find P(X)...
Can you help me ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's purely mathematical in nature.

Comment: as this is core to cryptography, i’d have a mind to keep it